# Search Result URL rewrite in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to rewrite my search result url from `http://www.site.ph/search/?keyword=dog` to `http://www.site.ph/search/dog`

Your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: codeigniter does that all by itself.. why are you using a query string with code igniter in the first place?

Comment: Find fixes using javascript instead. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this :

Go to your config file and modify following - application\config\config.php

```
$config['allow_get_array']       = TRUE;
$config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE;
```

Make enable_query_strings = FALSE , and try your new URL.
This might works. 
Thanks